Voice assistant not taking voice command in python
I am creating a voice assistant but it not taking any voice commands. The program is supposed to take my voice as a command and the program works according to the query. Right now there is not lots of functions. Right now it is just a "greet me" function which is written in another file and imported here
import speech_recognition 
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)
rate = engine.setProperty("rate",170)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def takeCommand():
    r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening.....")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.energy_threshold = 300
        audio = r.listen(source,0,4)

    try:
        print("Understanding..")
        query  = r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
        print(f"You Said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Say that again")
        return "None"
    return query
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if "wake up" in query:
            from greetme import greetMe
            greetMe()

            while True:
                query = takeCommand().lower()
                if "go to sleep" in query:
                    speak("Ok sir , You can me call anytime")
                    break 

Greetme function:
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty("rate",200)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def greetMe():
    hour  = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<=12:
        speak("Good Morning,sir")
    elif hour >12 and hour<=18:
        speak("Good Afternoon ,sir")

    else:
        speak("Good Evening,sir")

    speak("Please tell me, How can I help you ?")

this is a very simple function, nothing much happens here. Just I say wake up and the program greets me according to the time
output:
Listening.....
Understanding..
Say that again
Listening.....
Understanding..
Say that again
Listening.....

this is the output I get whenever I say something or say 'wakeup' it again runs the "take command" function not the greet me function. I even try to put "greet me" function in the same file but that also doesn't work.

Have you tried playing back to the recording to make sure its good enough quality?  Instead of except Exception as e, its recommended to catch the expected Exception type, but as long as you're doing that, try printing e to get more info.

Good day, I went through the code you provided, What I noticed was that the code was ok in both file, the main reason why your code was not working properly was because you omitted some imports in the greetme.py file and you didn't call the pyttsx3 package completely,
this is your greetme.py file
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty("rate",200)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def greetMe():
    hour  = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<=12:
        speak("Good Morning,sir")
    elif hour >12 and hour<=18:
        speak("Good Afternoon ,sir")

    else:
        speak("Good Evening,sir")

    speak("Please tell me, How can I help you ?")

The Major correction to this file will just to add the import and call the pyttsx3 package correctly and your code should work fine
here is the correct code for greetme.py
import pyttsx3
import datetime

engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty("rate",200)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def greetMe():
    hour  = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<=12:
        speak("Good Morning,sir")
    elif hour >12 and hour<=18:
        speak("Good Afternoon ,sir")

    else:
        speak("Good Evening,sir")

    speak("Please tell me, How can I help you ?")

correcting the greetme.py file as follows above should get the program up and running
#edit
(there were some errors I didn't see in these code try adjusting it as below)
made some adjustments to main.py code
import speech_recognition 
import pyttsx3

#and at this point
from greetme import greetMe
            
engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)
rate = engine.setProperty("rate",170)

def speak2(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def takeCommand():
    r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening.....")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.energy_threshold = 300
        audio = r.listen(source,0,4)

    try:
        print("Understanding..")
        query  = r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
        print(f"You Said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Say that again")
        return "None"
    return query
if __name__ == "__main__":
    query = ""
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if "wake up" in query:
            greetMe()

        # at this point   
        if "go to sleep" in query:
            speak2("Ok sir , You can me call anytime")
            break 

the test calls will be "wake up" for it to greet and  "go to sleep" to quit, make sure you are online and also make sure your microphone working fine

thanks for helping me i try this code but still the same issue its not taking the command when i say something or give some command it again goes to its listening function

I will make some adjustments to my post, to main.py code, try making this adjustment and tells me if it works

I have made the adjustment to post, you can try it out now, before trying it out, make sure your mic is working fine, sometimes the fault might be as a result of faulty mic, good luck
